# Laravel: how to find concrete implementation of a Facade?

Tags: php, laravel, facade

This is the link to source code of Laravel (v8 but it's not important) about Redis Facade

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php#L164

I would like to find the 'concrete' Redis class served by the facade itself.

How can I do? Where does Laravel framework bind this facade to a "real" class?

Comment: It's an abstract class, not linked to redis specifically, that you linked. Usually the concrete class is in the comment above the facade, if you open the Storage facade for example you will see `@see \Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager` which is the concrete implementation, For Redis facade it's `@see \Illuminate\Redis\RedisManager`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/facades#facade-class-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concrete implementation of a Facade in Laravel is served from the service container.

For `Redis` you can find in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/RedisServiceProvider.php`

In Laravel 9.3 you can see something like this

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('redis', function ($app) {
        $config = $app->make('config')->get('database.redis', []);

        return new RedisManager($app, Arr::pull($config, 'client', 'phpredis'), $config);
    });

    $this->app->bind('redis.connection', function ($app) {
        return $app['redis']->connection();
    });
}
```

> **`RedisManager` is the concrete implementation of the `Redis`. Whenever you call methods on the `Redis`, you're calling methods on the `RedisManager` only.**

Comment: Additional : You can also find it in the `Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php` at the near bottom where you can also find the other concrete implementation for other facades.